# Alternative error measure--maximize data to have residuals less than given threshold

Tags: error, mean-absolute-deviation

I am looking for a method which finds a linear model (2 input variables, everything reasonably close enough to normally distributed), but with an alternative measure of error.  Every error measure I am aware of seeks to minimize error, but I am approaching it from a different direction.  I would like to maximize the number of data points, the residual for which is less than a given threshold.  The threshold can be an absolute number or a percent of the $y$ variable (I am not sure which is more appropriate for my problem).  Does such a method exist (or alternatively, is there another method that is equivalent)?

Answer (score 2):

This is approximately what [support vector regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Regression) does.

Minimize $${\displaystyle {\frac {1}{2}}\|\beta\|^{2}}$$
subject to $${\displaystyle |y_{i}-x_i\beta -\beta_0|\leq \varepsilon }.$$

That is, it tries to get as many of the residuals as possible smaller than $\varepsilon$, with an additional penalty on the slopes.